# How to set up pnpm in run/debug in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I get the error for "Please specify npm or yarn package: cannot find binary file inside" after I try to set up the path of pnpm under `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM -> Package Management`. From [WebStorm doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#ws_npm_run_debug_scripts_from_npm_tool_window), that is how I should set up.

Does anyone know how to use pnpm in WebStorm?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing, node and npm then pnpm as global under my Mac that I do not have before.
`brew install node`
`npm i -g pnpm@x.x.x` make sure `x.x.x` version matched the version of my project
Then go to use `/usr/local/pin/pnpm` under "Preferences" -> "Languages & Frameworks" -> "Node.js and NPM" -> "Package Management"
and under "Run/Debug Configuration" select the `Project` for Package Management not the directory of pnpm under my project. I guess for somereason Webstorm can not use pnpm under my project